# parentheses around variable or lists use case?

Tags: python

What would be the use of adding parentheses around a variable ?

say :

```
myvar="testtest"
```

can also be :

```
(myvar)="testtest"
extravar=(myvar)
```

or with list :

```
mylist=([1,2,3])
```

As it seems all of them are syntactically correct by interpreter i wonder what would be the use case?

Comment: spanning multiple lines, for one

Comment: ***()*** are used for grouping, specifying tuples and generator expressions. In your case they make no sense.

Comment: These are all totally pointless uses of parentheses, in this case, for grouping, but they don't do anything here.

Comment: Everything except `(myvar)="testiest"` is just a side effect of the ability to parenthesize any expression. Parentheses around the target is a likely a side effect of the grammar rule that defines target lists for assignments.

Comment: It's not so much that there's a reason to *allow* the parentheses, as no reason to *disallow* them  (which would complicate the parser with no benefit).

Comment: @ Josh Friedlander care to explain a little ?

Comment: If you want to split a long line, you can use (otherwise useless) parentheses around the expression you want to split, like `from foo import (bar, baz, quux, ... many more items split over several lines)`

Comment: There doesn't need to be a justification to allow degenerate cases of facilities that have use cases in their non-degenerate applications. It'd be more work (and more rules for people to remember) to disallow them.

Comment: You're familiar with `(a, b) = (1, 2)` as valid syntax, right? Once you've implemented that, you'd have to go out of your way to stop `(a) = (1)` from also being allowed, and... what would be the point?

Comment: I generally consider "what's the use case of syntax-X" questions categorically off-topic; they're simultaneously too-broad and opinion-based: broad because it's asking for an enumeration of an unconstrained set (people can come up with new uses in the future), opinion-based because one person's legitimate use case is another person' bad idea.